# Memory usage within perl

Tags: perl, process, memory-management

I have been looking for a perl's internal variable or module than can give me the memory usage for variables/hashes/arrays and called within the script I am analyzing .. for the script's used memory I found:

```
open( STAT , "</proc/$$/stat" )
or die "Unable to open stat file";
@stat = split /\s+/ , <STAT>;
close( STAT );
```

but I want to track a particular variable not the process' memory.

Does something like that exist???

Comment: [GTop](http://p3rl.org/GTop#GTop::Mem) has a better API than the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look at the [Devel::Size](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aSize) module.